# how to I get a user's IP address when separate client and server apps, in Node with Nest.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nestjs

I have two apps, one front end (react.js) and one a REST API back-end(nest.js based on express.js). How do I get the IP address of the user accessing the back-end when the front-end client makes a request to the back-end?

I checked this question and try the solutions

[With separate client and server apps, how do I get a user's IP address, in Node with Koa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554357/with-separate-client-and-server-apps-how-do-i-get-a-users-ip-address-in-node)

[Express.js: how to get remote client address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849687/express-js-how-to-get-remote-client-address)

but I get server IP of front-end not client IP.

Is there a way without any change in front-end app, I get real client IP in nest.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may install a library called `request-ip`:

```
npm i --save request-ip
npm i --save-dev @types/request-ip
```

In `main.ts` file inject request-ip middleware within your app:

```
app.use(requestIp.mw());
```

Now you can access clientIp from request object:

```
req.clientIp
```

Another way is by defining a decorator:

```
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as requestIp from 'request-ip';

export const IpAddress = createParamDecorator((data, req) => {
    if (req.clientIp) return req.clientIp;
    return requestIp.getClientIp(req);
});
```

And you can use the decorator in controller:

```
@Get('/users')
async users(@IpAddress() ipAddress){
}
```

Check the following [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/195#issuecomment-521637851) in github.

Comment: For me, req was of type ExecutionContext. So instead of calling it req, call it ctx and do:
`const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();`

Comment: `request-ip` hasn't been properly maintained for ~3 years now. The IP address it picks for header can be forged.

Answer (score 18):

According to the NestJS docs, there's a decorator available to get the request Ip Address. It's used like this:

```js
import {Get, Ip} from "@nestjs/common"

@Get('myEndpoint')
async myEndpointFunc(@Ip() ip){
  console.log(ip)
}
```

Here's a complete list of decorators that can be used:
https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators

Comment: Not worked. I got the IP: ::ffff:127.0.0.1

Comment: If you're working on your local host that's the response you'll get @Henry

Answer (score 5):

You can extract **IP address** from a `Request` object.

I am using it as a middleware to print user's IP address in a log entry, here is how I do that:

```js
import { Injectable, Logger, NestMiddleware } from "@nestjs/common";
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

@Injectable()
export class HttpLoggerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    private logger = new Logger();

    use(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
        const { ip, method, originalUrl } = request;

        response.on("finish", () => {
            const msg = `${ip} ${method} ${originalUrl}`;
            this.logger.log(msg);
        });

        next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the IP from headers in @Request() req:

```
const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
  @Post("/mypath")
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  async intention(
      @Body() body: MyRequest,
      @Req() requestToReadIp: Request
  ): Promise<PurchaseIntentionResponse>  {
      const ips = requestToReadIp.headers['x-forwarded-for'] as string
      const userIp = ips.split(",")[0]
      ...
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are fine using 3rd-party library. You can check request-ip

https://github.com/pbojinov/request-ip